# Build gdal with mrsid DSDK on fedora 21

Tags: fedora, gdal

I'm trying to build gdal 1.11.2 from source with mrsid DSDK enabling gdal to able to read mrsid file. I did all the required things and after I run make it shows me the following error message:

```
GNUmakefile:46: recipe for target 'gdalinfo' failed
make[1]: *** [gdalinfo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/fedora/Downloads/gdal-1.11.2/apps'
GNUmakefile:69: recipe for target 'apps-target' failed
make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
```

So anyone who had same problem please help me i've been messing with this almost a week, and searched everywhere.

UPDATE: I think the MrSID DSDK is having problem i guess.

```
/bin/ld: warning: libtbb.so.2, needed by /home/fedora/Downloads/MrSID_DSDK-9.1.0.4045-linux.x86-64.gcc41/Raster_DSDK/lib/libltidsdk.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/fedora/Downloads/MrSID_DSDK-9.1.0.4045-linux.x86-64.gcc41/Raster_DSDK/lib/libltidsdk.so: undefined reference to `tbb::pipeline::pipeline()'
/home/fedora/Downloads/MrSID_DSDK-9.1.0.4045-linux.x86-64.gcc41/Raster_DSDK/lib/libltidsdk.so: undefined reference to `tbb::pipeline::add_filter(tbb::filter&)'
/home/fedora/Downloads/MrSID_DSDK-9.1.0.4045-linux.x86-64.gcc41/Raster_DSDK/lib/libltidsdk.so: undefined reference to `tbb::pipeline::run(unsigned long)'
/home/fedora/Downloads/MrSID_DSDK-9.1.0.4045-linux.x86-64.gcc41/Raster_DSDK/lib/libltidsdk.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for tbb::filter'
/home/fedora/Downloads/MrSID_DSDK-9.1.0.4045-linux.x86-64.gcc41/Raster_DSDK/lib/libltidsdk.so: undefined reference to `tbb::filter::~filter()'
/home/fedora/Downloads/MrSID_DSDK-9.1.0.4045-linux.x86-64.gcc41/Raster_DSDK/lib/libltidsdk.so: undefined reference to `tbb::task_scheduler_init::default_num_threads()'
/home/fedora/Downloads/MrSID_DSDK-9.1.0.4045-linux.x86-64.gcc41/Raster_DSDK/lib/libltidsdk.so: undefined reference to `tbb::pipeline::~pipeline()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
GNUmakefile:46: recipe for target 'gdalinfo' failed
make[1]: *** [gdalinfo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/fedora/Downloads/gdal-1.11.2/apps'
GNUmakefile:69: recipe for target 'apps-target' failed
make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
```

Comment: This isn't sufficient debug info. The error is either further up or is suppressed/hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue before. I was able to solve this by adding this line to my setup:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/Raster_DSDK/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Link: https://gist.github.com/oeon/6527004 (Not my work, just a helpful person)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the tbb library.

```
tbb.i686 : The Threading Building Blocks library abstracts low-level threading
         : details
tbb-devel.i686 : The Threading Building Blocks C++ headers and shared
               : development libraries
tbb-doc.i686 : The Threading Building Blocks documentation
```

Try

```
apt-get install libtbb-dev
```